# How to check if a pointer is null in C++ Visual 2010

Tags: c++, pointers

I am having problems here if I want to check if `eerste` points to nothing I get

> Blockquote
>
> Unhandled exception at 0x003921c6 in
>   Bank.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation
>   reading location 0xccccccd0.

and I am kinda wondering why he justs skips the if statement or doens't stop when the object `eerste` points to nothing

```
Bank::Bank()
{
 LijstElement *eerste = NULL;
 LijstElement *laatste = NULL;
}

 Rekening * Bank::getRekening(int rekNr)
{

 if(NULL != eerste)
 {
  LijstElement *nummer = eerste;
  while(nummer->volgende!= NULL)
  {
   Rekening *een = nummer->getRekening();
   if(een->getRekNr()==rekNr)
    {
     return een;
    }
   else
   {
    nummer = nummer->volgende;
   }
  }
 }
 return NULL;   
}
```

Comment: If this is VS2010, use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you have to change

```
Bank::Bank()
{
    eerste = NULL;
    laatste = NULL;
}
```

because they are probably declared in your class as member variables and you're declaring them as local variables.

As Fred Larson proposed, you can also use initialization lists.

```
Bank::Bank() : eerste(NULL), laatste(NULL)  
{
//whatever else you are planning to do in your constructor
}
```

Comment: I got rid of the stars for you.  You need the pointers to be null, not their values.

Comment: Better yet, let's make them initializers.

Comment: @Kristo: I think I got in there before you ;-)

Answer (score 6):

eerste and laatste are not your Bank class's member variables, but the local variables of the contructor (even if members are defined, the local vars override them in the constructor - so the actual member variables remain unassigned)

I'd propose to use a naming convention (add a m_ prefix to member variables) and a simple initialization list :

```
class Bank
{
public:     
  Bank() : m_eerste(NULL), m_laatste(NULL)
  {}

  private:
    LijstElement *m_eerste;
    LijstElement *m_laatste;

};
```

Comment: You mean "hide", not "override".

Answer (score 1):

The syntax in your constructor suggests `eerste` and `laatste` are not member variables (and are thus illegal to reference in `getRekening`.)

Could you please post correct code including the portion in your header file?

Edit: Other than that, it looks like you're trying to use an uninitialized pointer. (Which points to nothing but not NULL, either.)